# Image is not load properly in full page image slider in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to load a full page `image` slider in my website. But in `image` slider Images are not load properly. May be it's a javascript related problem.

**here is my script**

```
$("#menutoggle").click(function() {
    $('.xs-menu').toggleClass('displaynone');
});
//add active class on menu
$('ul li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
//drop down menu    
$(".drop-down").hover(function() {
    $('.mega-menu').addClass('display-on');
});
$(".drop-down").mouseleave(function() {
    $('.mega-menu').removeClass('display-on');
});
```

Full code is [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLOgNL#anon-login).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this `CSS`

```
.active{
    background:#090909 !important;  
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvVwYy

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one, as it is working, but rather complex one:
https://github.com/codrops/Blueprint-BackgroundSlideshow